# Unable to get an id from the database after doing insert using sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Assuming this model:

```
class Pipeline(Base):
    __tablename__ = "pipeline"
    pipeline_id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    pipeline_version_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    update_ts = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    config = Column(TEXT(), nullable=True)
    parser_version = Column(String, nullable=True)
```

And this insert code:

```
        async with self.sessionFactory() as session:
            async with session.begin():
                query = select(Pipeline).filter_by(pipeline_id=pipeline_id).filter_by(is_active=True)
                result = await session.execute(query)
                active_pipelines = result.scalars().all()
                for entry in active_pipelines:
                    entry.is_active = False
                    self.logger.info(f"Marking pipeline/version {entry.pipeline_id}/{entry.pipeline_version_id} inactive")

                self.logger.info(f"Creating update_pipeline:  {updated_pipeline}")

                session.add(updated_pipeline)
                pipeline_version_id = updated_pipeline.pipeline_version_id
                self.logger.info('adding updated pipeline with version id {id}'.format(id=str(pipeline_version_id)))
```

When I run this, it is returning a `null` `pipeline_version_id`

[Edit]

Here are other alternatives I tried:

```
        async with self.sessionFactory() as session:
            async with session.begin():
                query = select(Pipeline).filter_by(pipeline_id=pipeline_id).filter_by(is_active=True)
                result = await session.execute(query)
                active_pipelines = result.scalars().all()
                for entry in active_pipelines:
                    entry.is_active = False
                    self.logger.info(f"Marking pipeline/version {entry.pipeline_id}/{entry.pipeline_version_id} inactive")
                self.logger.info(f"Creating update_pipeline:  {updated_pipeline}")
                session.add(updated_pipeline)

        pipeline_version_id = updated_pipeline.pipeline_version_id
        self.logger.info('adding updated pipeline with version id {id}'.format(id=str(pipeline_version_id)))
```

Result: `Failed to update DB. Error: Instance <Pipeline at 0x110c31da0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)`

```
        async with self.sessionFactory() as session:
            async with session.begin():
                query = select(Pipeline).filter_by(pipeline_id=pipeline_id).filter_by(is_active=True)
                result = await session.execute(query)
                active_pipelines = result.scalars().all()
                for entry in active_pipelines:
                    entry.is_active = False
                    self.logger.info(f"Marking pipeline/version {entry.pipeline_id}/{entry.pipeline_version_id} inactive")
                self.logger.info(f"Creating update_pipeline:  {updated_pipeline}")
                session.add(updated_pipeline)

            pipeline_version_id = updated_pipeline.pipeline_version_id
            self.logger.info('adding updated pipeline with version id {id}'.format(id=str(pipeline_version_id)))
```

Result: `Failed to update DB. Error: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/xd2s)`

How do i get the ID of the inserted record without doing another query?

These are my dependencies:

```
python = "^3.7"
setuptools = "<58"
fastapi = "^0.54.1"
gunicorn = "<20.0"
uvicorn = "^0.11.5"
sqlalchemy = "^1.4.25"
apache-airflow="1.10.10"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.1"
```

Here is my session creation:

```
def create_session_factory(db_conn=None):
    #
    # Using https://rogulski.it/blog/sqlalchemy-14-async-orm-with-fastapi/
    #
    if not db_conn:
        db_conn = get_default_parser_db_conn_str()
    global _engine
    if not _engine:
        _engine = create_async_engine(db_conn, **DB_ENGINE_OPTIONS)
    sessionFactory = sessionmaker(_engine, class_=AsyncSession)
    sessionFactory.configure()
    return sessionFactory
```

and the DB_ENGINE_OPTIONS

```
DB_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    "poolclass": QueuePool,
    "pool_size": 10,
    "max_overflow": 50,
    "pool_recycle": 3600,
    "pool_timeout": 30
}
```

Any help appreciated.

this is my first time at async DB calls with python, so I am sure i am missing something.

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/D2jCDHUq) works for me. It is adapted from [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/asyncio/async_orm.html).

Comment: Hmm. but i thought you dont need to use `session.commit` if you are using `session.begin` ?

Comment: That's correct. The transaction will automatically commit if the `with` block exits without errors. [This](https://pastebin.com/0UVTs706) works, too.

Comment: hmm.. not working for me. I think the difference is the async part which you are not using.

Comment: Which "async part" am I not using? I'm certainly using `postgresql+asyncpg://` and async/await.

Comment: You have to `flush` your session after `add` to have `id`, `id` will be assigned after `commit` or `flush` but your commit is done after this line `pipeline_version_id = updated_pipeline.pipeline_version_id`

Comment: @GordThompson you are right. Sorry, i misspoke

Comment: @jorzel right, that is correct. however, shouldnt the flush have happened when the `session.begin` context ends? And therefore, the id should be available after that? That is not happening.

Comment: @GordThompson I edited my question, to list all the things I tried, along with the result I got. Sorry, I should have done that earlier.

Comment: @feroze session.begin is only being closed when context ends. You have to explicitly flush or commit it.

Comment: @jorzel - Actually, when we exit the `async with session.begin():` block, the transaction will automatically be committed if no error has occurred.

Comment: @feroze - Are you using `expire_on_commit=False` ?

Comment: @GordThompson you are right, sorry for confusion

Comment: @GordThompson edited and added the session init code.

Comment: @GordThompson any feedback?

Comment: Have you tried using `expire_on_commit=False` ?

Comment: Yeah I did. That didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, who answered.

Ultimately, just adding a `session.flush()` after the call to `session.add(obj)` gave me what i needed.